# HTML Forms saving it on the serverside

Tags: html, asp-classic, google-docs

Hi i am having an asp webpage which i am creating to make a ticketing system but the issue is that if lets say a user pressed a seat number A1 and he submits the form the data is stored in google docs but i am not able to make that seat disabled for the other users..how can i do this? for testing purposes i have uploaded the page to this site
[This is the page that i am trying to create it is still in very early stage so the submit wont work..](http://singaporetelugusamajam.org/Ticketing_system.asp)

AS u can see that i have href to A1 only and it is having some background color issues which i have to deal with that as well..my understanding is that i have to do this on the serverside so that the next person will be shown as that seat is taken thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> i am not able to make that seat disabled for the other users..how can i do this?

When generating the page, your server side code must look up what seats are available and show those.

When a seat request is submitted then the server side code needs to check if it is still available and present an error message ("Sorry, it seems that someone else has reserved seat A1 while you were making your choice, please select an alternative seat") if it isn't.

The specifics depend on how you are accessing your data store.

Comment: hi quentin yes man u got the exact point so u are saying that i have to store this in a database? cause i  am using a google forms to process my data and it is being saved in the google forms and i am not sure how to read from the google forms and process it, so is there anyway for me to do this? if it is not possible and the worst case scenarion would be to make this as xml datastore is that ok?

Comment: You have to store it somewhere. Google Forms is, AFAIK, a write only API. An XML datastore would be a silly idea, XML is a great data transport format but is very inefficient to search and would require all sorts of file locking stuff that a database would take care of for you.

Comment: where do u think is the best place to store then a sql database perhaps?

Comment: That's the usual choice. A map reduce based system such as CouchDB is also an option.